# Xamarin iOS How can I rotate my screen slower

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, landscape-portrait, portrait

When I'm moving my screen from portrait to landscape I want the rotation to be slower, meaning it will be more seen how the layout is moved, rather than so fast.

Comment: Is this just for debugging the animation or do you actually want that effect in the released app?

Comment: I need the effect in release app